# Target sum of an infinite stream of numbers in python

Tags: python, algorithm, stream, sum, logic

I'm trying to find is a target sum could be found from an infinite stream of numbers in Python. The numbers are positive (numbers> 0), unique and the numbers are indefinite. I believe the answer would be to use dynamic programming or heap but can't quite figure out a logic.

Any help on possible data structure or flow of logic to try.

Thank you so much.

e.g

```
    nums = [ 99,85,1,3,6,72,7,9,22,....]
    targetSum = 27

output: True
Explanation: 1+6+22 = 27(targetSum)
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean infinite? I think you mean a list of numbers.

Comment: Hello, yes infinite in the sense continuous stream of numbers. We don't know the length of the stream.

Comment: you want us to implement an algorithm for you, that determines a set of members from a finite list, that being added results in targetSum?

What did you try so far?

If the nums is finite (with `n` elements)
try perhaps following:

- try out for all `n` possibilities pick out one entry from the list and see whether it is `targetSum`
- pick two entries from the list  and see whether it's sum is `targetSum`
if no result is found try with 3 entries, ... until you tried it with n entries.

Look at the module `itertools` which has the `combinations` function, that mioght help you

Comment: you mean `indefinite` (undefined / the length is unknown it is not defined) or `infinite` the list will not fit into memory as there is always another member that you didn't access so far in it)

Comment: Hi @gelonida, thanks for the possible solution. I mean infinite wherein the list won't fit in memory. It would be great if a logic could be suggested on how to go about this problem.

Comment: will your stream ever contain negative numbers or can we assume all members are > 0?

Comment: All numbers are > 0. Let me add this to the original question too, sorry about that

Comment: can numbers repeat or are all numbers unique?

Comment: We can assume that the numbers are unique. Adding, this too to the original question.

Comment: then you can use a set that stores all encountered numbers smaller than `targetSum`
and tries to find a combination, that adds up to `targetSum`
This set will never have more members than `targetSum`. If `targetSum` is a huge number this could still explode your memory requirements though.

Comment: Do you have any limits on the value of the target sum?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set to keep track of all the possible sums given the numbers so far in the iterations. For each iteration, add the current number to each existing sum in the set to add to the set, and add the current number itself to the set. Return `True` when the target sum is indeed in the set:

```
def has_sum(nums, targetSum):
    sums = set()
    for i in nums:
        sums.update([s + i for s in sums if s + i <= targetSum])
        if i <= targetSum:
            sums.add(i)
        if targetSum in sums:
            return True
    return False
```

so that:

```
has_sum([99, 85, 1, 3, 6, 72, 7, 9, 22], 29)
```

returns `True` (because 1 + 6 + 22 = 29), and that:

```
has_sum([99, 85, 1, 3, 6, 72, 7, 9, 22], 27)
```

returns `False` (because the expected output in your question is incorrect).

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Its a nice, quick brute force solution but what if the stream has thousands of numbers in the stream. How can we manage memory in that case?

Comment: Then you'd be trading time for memory saving, since if you don't keep the previous sums in memory you'd be spending time revisiting all previous numbers to recalculate all the previous sums for every new number.

Comment: Thank you @blhsing. Yes, we would have to do a tradeoff in that case but was wondering if there was a way to store only selected previous sum (not sure if this criteria could be formulated)

Comment: Note.  You only actually need to store sums below or equal to the target sum.  Also if you make it a dictionary saying the last number added to get to this sum, then you can work backwards and produce the subset that actually added up to the sum.

Comment: @btilly Note that the OP added this constraint after I wrote this answer.

Comment: Good to know. :-)

Comment: Updated the answer to account for the new constraint of all numbers being positive.

Answer (score 0):

@Pavis,

One idea that I can think of is to use tight graph.  You can do the following:

1. add each number element that is less than the sum into the graph as a node
2. each new node is connected to every other node already present in the graph
3. after addition to graph, compute the sum using breadth first search from the lowest element

I think this process is slow tho

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively try to satisfy the target sum with or without the first number in the given sequence, until there is no more number in the given sequence, or until the given target sum is no longer positive (since you mentioned in the comment that all given numbers are positive):

```
def has_sum(nums, targetSum):
    if not nums or targetSum <= 0:
        return False
    first, *rest = nums
    return first == targetSum or has_sum(rest, targetSum - first) or has_sum(rest, targetSum)
```

so that:

```
has_sum([99, 85, 1, 3, 6, 72, 7, 9, 22], 29)
```

returns `True` (because 1 + 6 + 22 = 29), and that:

```
has_sum([99, 85, 1, 3, 6, 72, 7, 9, 22], 27)
```

returns `False` (because the expected output in your question is incorrect).

EDIT: To avoid performance impact from copying the input sequence minus the first item to `rest` in every call, the code above can be improved with an index instead:

```
def has_sum(nums, targetSum, index=0):
    if index == len(nums) or targetSum <= 0:
        return False
    num = nums[index]
    return num == targetSum or has_sum(nums, targetSum - num, index + 1) or has_sum(nums, targetSum, index + 1)
```